# How to open a Kali Linux fold from Windows to recover photos

Tags: data-recovery, logging, kali-linux

Backstory:

So I am in the log-in loop. I can't log into my account.

And because of the fact that I've previously made the alt key responsible for changing layouts now, I can't access the virtual console (when I press all combination alt+ctrl+f* Linux just changes layouts from eng to ru). But I can perfectly access the console in Ubuntu, which I installed just yesterday.

Problem:

Because I've never expected such a problem to arise I stored part of my photos in the folder on Kali Linux desktop.
I wanted to download them to the Google disk later, but I didn't make it in time.

Question:

Can I somehow open the folder with my photos (which is located on Kali Desktop) from other operating system: Windows or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a live disc or multi boot installation of Ubuntu or other linux distributions, you can boot from it. Then you have the open the file manager and double-click the Kali linux partition to mount it. Then you can navigate to the photos directory of Kali linux. Windows cannot access linux extended partitions natively, and I also don't know of there is any tool available for this.